# How to have JQuery wait to complete a section of code before moving on with MVC Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, modal-dialog

I want the user to press a download button. The button will call a JQuery function that will start a loading modal, run a Url.Action request, then stop the modal as soon as the Action has completed running. Unfortunately, JS starts and then stops my modal even though it hasn't finished running my Url.Action

Code:

```
$('#DownloadBtn').click(function () {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    modal.style.display = "block"; // starts the loading modal display when button is pressed

    location.href = '@Url.Action("Download", "Home")'; //action to download begins (this usually takes around 10 seconds to run through, that's why I want that modal running until the action is finished)

    modal.style.display = "none"; //this switches to none before the above Action has even completed
}
```

Comment: Setting `location.href` will cause the current page to be unloaded, so you cannot make any changes to the DOM after that point. It seems almost entirely redundant to need to hide the modal anyway, as the action of transferring the page will cause the content to be updated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a setTimeout to delay the modal close like so

```js
$('#DownloadBtn').click(function () {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    modal.style.display = "block";
    location.href = '@Url.Action("Download", "Home")';
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        modal.style.display = "none"
    }, 10000); // Delay in ms
}
```

Waiting for the `@Url.Action` to complete would be the ideal solution, but I couldn't find anything on if that is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML)

I suggest you give this a read

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

then come back with questions.

There are many ways to use AJAX. You can ignore the XML part it isn't a requirement.

The w3schools article illustrates using AJAX without a framework, vanilla javascript. But you can use JQuery (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and other frameworks to achieve the same without having to know the details though there's still a learning curve. I don't use frameworks for this, vanilla JS is perfect and tiny footprint.

I would post code but I keep getting format errors, sorry.

Comment: So I have tried Ajax, however, I would need to pass the file from the Controllers Action and then somehow download it the response in the success function. I don't think this is possible to do. success: function(response){ //response has the zip but cant be downloaded from here }

Comment: success: function (returnValue) {
        window.location = '/Reports/Download?file=' + returnValue;
    } --- full example and explanation @ https://forums.asp.net/t/2081846.aspx?Download+file+in+mvc+using+ajax and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/download-file-in-mvc-4/ . Old but still works